# 401 Authorization Required Error in Using Web API

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services, jsp

I am a newbie in the use of Web-API.have a web-API by using which i can get response in Json format.I am using this API in jsp usinh jquery Ajax.
Here is the structure of web-API .

```
http://pnrbuddy.com/api/check_pnr/pnr/<10 digit PNR number>/format/<xml|json> / pbapikey / <your public api key> / pbapisign(private key) / <HMAC signature>
```

Please see the API parameters names and their meaning.

I am trying to use this by passing values as..

```
http://pnrbuddy.com/api/check_pnr/pnr/1234567890/format/json/pbapikey/c70a600b160e9a1fd4c6aa772e63e612/pbapisign/71988fc2bacfe995e96e65c1cbfed3dc2ba613c8
```

Buu while executing i am getting error as ..

```
401 Authorization Required.
```

and In the Response of firebug.this message..

```
Reload the page to get source for: http://pnrbuddy.com/api/check_pnr/pnr/1234567890/format/json/pbapikey/c70a600b160e9a1fd4c6aa772e63e612/pbapisign/71988fc2bacfe995e96e65c1cbfed3dc2ba613c8
```

How to resolve this .

My HMAC generation code.

```
            String mykey = "Private Key";
    String test = "pnrjson6b17f33e25e2d8197462d1c6bcb0b130";
    try {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(mykey.getBytes(),
                "HmacSHA1");
        mac.init(secret);
        byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(test.getBytes());
        for (byte b : digest) {
            System.out.format("%02x", b);
        }
        System.out.println();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

My new API URL values..

```
http://pnrbuddy.com/api/check_pnr/pnr/1234567890/format/json/pbapikey/6b17f33e25e2d8197462d1c6bcb0b130/pbapisign/ebb4279d9b8cc3e011a7d7a46248c4ac456a6ca3
```

Still i am getting same authorization error. Why?

Here is my client side code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#click").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://pnrbuddy.com/api/check_pnr/pnr/1234567890/format/json/pbapikey/6b17f33e25e2d8197462d1c6bcb0b130/pbapisign/8dd7f570509ab9b7d27cc182982d49ca63fb45d6",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#response").html(data.d);
                    }

                });
            });
        });
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <button id="click">GetPNR Status</button>
    <div id="response"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check whether the API requires you to send authorization parameters like key, oAuth token, etc.

Comment: @SelvarajMA Sir it requires public and private key and HMAC Signature ..My query is from where would i get public and private keys for using this API

Comment: @SelvarajMA Please see the link http://pnrbuddy.com/hauth/api?page=keys I am trying to use this API

Comment: The format looks OK, I think you may need to recheck your public key. Here is reference[http://pnrbuddy.com/hauth/api?page=keys].

Comment: @OwenCao What public key i need to send.Actually sir i am trying this for the first time so have no idea ..At present i am passing their public key what they have mentioned in the example i.e c70a600b160e9a1fd4c6aa772e63e612 .Do i need to change and if yes with what?

Comment: @Pranav Check your pnrbuddy profile/dashboard page. I think there should be a way to generate those keys in their website.

Comment: Have you logged in pnrbuddy? Log in via your Google or Facebook account, and then go to /ME/My DEV Account/Dev Registration, click register, and then go to /Manage API Key to generate your new Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I think you need to register as a developer in pnrbuddy(steps are in my comments).
You need to use your own keys to access the api.

And then refer this:
http://pnrbuddy.com/hauth/api?page=keys

Comment: Hey, man, I think you missed the pnr number in the String test.

Comment: It should be  String test = "json" + PUBLIC_KEY + PNR_NUMBER;

Comment: json6b17f33e25e2d8197462d1c6bcb0b130pnr . Is it correct to generate HMAC

Comment: It should be json6b17f33e25e2d8197462d1c6bcb0b1301234567890

Comment: with json6b17f33e25e2d8197462d1c6bcb0b1301234567890 my status code is 200 OK but i am not able to get any response in  $("#response").html(data.d); .Why